# How to count new data before executing a function again

Tags: django, celery

I have this function that do automatic execution of `send_sms` function when certain conditions are met. That it will execute if the count for specific levels are detected.

I'm using celery to automatically execute it when needed. But my problem now is like this.

if the `responses.count() >= 50:` then it will execute `send_sms` function. but when it reaches `51` after the first execution it is still executing and it must not. I want it to recount again another `NEW` 50 for another execution.

How can I do it? Thanks!

```
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=3),
    )
    if responses.count() >= 50:
        send_sms(request)

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for that you could just simply use the [modulo operator](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-python-modulo-operator-what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python-solved/), like this:

```
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=3),
    )

    count = responses.count()
    if not (count % 50) and count > 0:
        send_sms(request)

    return HttpResponse(200)
```

The main changes were at `if not (count % 50) and count > 0:`, where there are 2 logical operations.

The first one `not (count % 50)` means that every number that is divisible by 50 will return `True`, which are 50, 100, 150, etc.

However there's a catch, `0` will also return `True` for the first operation and that's not something that you want. So that's the reason for the second operation `count > 0`.